# Validate array command

Tags: arrays, json, node.js, discord.js

As I put in the question I have these commands that work correctly but are not validated, which means that if I enter a name it simply makes the record not validating if this name already exists inside the array.
It sounds simple but I've tried to validate using `array.find` and then compare with the value before inserting but it does not work: for example in the command `track` I'm trying to validate if the name you are trying to insert already exists.   In the command `untrack` if the name does not exist send a message, because that is another problem: if the name does not exist the command deletes the last inserted record.

If someone has the knowledge on how to make such validations, I would appreciate a little help.

```
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command === "track") {
  let [playerName, playerType] = args;
  list.push({
    name: playerName,
    type: playerType
  }) var logger = fs.createWriteStream('./realmtrack-config.json')
  logger.write(JSON.stringify(config)) message.reply(`Player being tracked!`);
}

if (command === "untrack") {
  let [playerName, playerType] = args;
  let entry_to_delete = list.find((e: any) => e.name === playerName);
  list.splice(list.indexOf(entry_to_delete), 1);
  var logger = fs.createWriteStream('./realmtrack-config.json');
  logger.write(JSON.stringify(config));
  message.reply(`${playerName} stopped being tracked!`);
}
```

Comment: So you want to search through a list of objects to work out if a player is currently being tracked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an array of objects

```
let list = [
  { name: "Joe", type: "Cool" },
  { name: "Sally", type: "Cool"}
]
```

You could create the below function to check if "Sally" is the name of one of the objects.

```
function(obj) {
  return obj.name === "Sally"
}
```

We can make this shorter with ES6 arrow functions

```
obj => obj.name === "Sally"
```

Next, we can scour `list` for an argument which will return `true` when passed to that function.

```
list.some(obj => obj.name === "Sally")
```

`.some` will return false only if all of the elements in an array will return false when passed to the callback function. Otherwise, it returns true.

We can add the below line near the start of your message handler, then.

```
const isBeingTracked = list.some(obj => obj.name === args[0])
```

For the `track` command, you could add `if(!isBeingTracked) { /* ... */ }` (the `!` means "not"). For the `untrack` command, you could add `if(isBeingTracked) { /* ... */ }`. `/* ... */` is what you would replace for actual code.